# Using child as a function parameter instead of parent

Tags: c++

Silly question here, but I can't seem to find a clear answer because of my lack of experience with terminology.
 Say I have a class

```
Class Char
{
    friend void function(Char object);
    protected:
        float x, y;
};
void function(Char object){
    // access object.x and object.y
}
```

And that class has several child classes:

```
Class Char1 : public Char
{
   ...
};

Class Char2 : public Char
{
   ...
};
```

Is it possible to use a `Char1` or `Char2` object as a parameter for `function(Char object)`, since they both inherit the values that the function will use?

Thanks and sorry for the silly question

Comment: This is not valid C++ code. Fix it and try doing what you are wondering about.

Comment: Classes are inherited like this: class Char1 : public Char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @lubo-antonov that this code does not have correct syntax, however if I understand correctly that "Char1" and "Char2" are meant to be classes that inherit from a class called "Char" then yes, you can create a function for example `function foo(Char obj)` that will receive an object of type "Char1" or "Char2" as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But you should really pass by pointer or reference.

So you should define `Char` like this:

```
class Char{
    public:
        friend void function(Char &c); // or const Char &     

    protected:
        float x, y;
};
```

and `function` like this:

```
void function(Char &c){}
```

(which you probably wanted to do anyway)

so that you aren't copying 2 floats every time you call the function

and you can pass in `Char` or any derived class of `Char`

Answer (score 1):

Your function is being passed an argument by value, so `Char1` will be partially copied ([sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)) to the stack as `Char`. If you want to deal with the original `Char1` object, declare passing by reference:

```
void function(Char &c) {
    // ...
}
```